# iOS app submission not working

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, binaries

I am trying to submit an iOS app through iTunes Connect.

However, when I try to validate the app it gives me an error saying : "This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with the Team ID.

Is this because I am using different accounts for creating the provisioning profiles and for iTunes connect ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have submitted your app before signed with a developer certificate from one account and now your trying to do it from another.

To fix it visit this website http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2012/12/04/use-a-provisioning-profile-associated-with-team-id/

## Edit

---

I do think that using different accounts for creating the provisioning profiles and for iTunes connect will cause the issue. So just switch the provisioning files from the prov. acct for the itunes connect account. Provisioning files are easy to make, and Apple has a tutorial on what to do when you try to create one.